# Ubunut 16.04 weak wifi signal (using hp-notebook with Ralink wireless adapter)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

I know this question has been discussed before a lot but unfortunately I was unable to fix my problem from many of the threads discussed before. It's been like a month since i have started using Ubuntu 16.04. I dual boot it with windows( although i am not using windows anymore). I get good signals when i am 2-3 meters of my wifi router but when i go beyond that, signal reduces and disconnects very quickly. Although i get good signal on windows. It is really problematic now because i have to use Internet at my university but can't do that. Below is summary of following commands.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
lsusb
lsmod
iwconfig
ifconfig -a
sudo iwlist scan
```

I have already preformed updating my kernel, iwconfig power off, and many other tricks which i don't remember anymore but it is not working.

> lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

> uname -a

```
Linux curiosity-HP-1000-Notebook-PC 4.4.24-040424-generic #201610071138 SMP Fri Oct 7 15:39:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> sudo lshw -class network

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: a4:17:31:a5:57:e8
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.24-040424-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2500000-c250ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c2404000-c2404fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff
```

> lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

Output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:539a]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT5390R 802.11b/g/n 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1839]
--
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Hanksville 10/100 Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:1854]
    Kernel modules: ndiswrapper
```

>
    lsusb

output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> lsmod

output

```
Module                  Size  Used by
msr                    16384  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  1
ccm                    20480  1
wl                   6365184  0
arc4                   16384  2
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
cfg80211              565248  3 wl,mac80211,rt2x00lib
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
intel_rapl             20480  0
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
coretemp               16384  0
snd                    81920  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
ndiswrapper           286720  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
mei_me                 32768  0
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
cryptd                 20480  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
i915                 1208320  4
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        135168  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   360448  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  3
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
fjes                   28672  0
```

> iwconfig

output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"UPC6350189"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 08:95:2A:88:86:70   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:103  Invalid misc:221   Missed beacon:0
```

> ifconfig -a

output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:372512 (372.5 KB)  TX bytes:372512 (372.5 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:17:31:a5:57:e8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:908:d80:1c20::7/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:908:d80:1c20:52f0:ead9:762c:95cc/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:908:d80:1c20:3c71:9e73:517f:1ce/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::13d4:18b8:8661:b0d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29816 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31948945 (31.9 MB)  TX bytes:4370093 (4.3 MB)
```

> grep -i blacklist /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

output

```
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
```

> sudo iwlist scan

output:

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 08:95:2A:88:86:70
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC6350189"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000042eac449f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A55504336333530313839
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0501002F0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A3C191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606081100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400080000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201000C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 46057208010000
          Cell 02 - Address: 08:95:2A:88:24:C9
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC6405478"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000017f54a5d8f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A55504336343035343738
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0501002E0000
                    IE: Unknown: ....................................
```

Comment: Are there any clues in `dmesg`?

Comment: Have you checked for `Software & Updates > additional drivers` for your wifi card?

Comment: Your wireless adapter is Ralink RT5390, not a Realtek.

Comment: @katutxakurra Yes i have installed all of the additional drivers.

Comment: @GrannySez i am not sure about dmesg.. how do i analyze that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the RTL8101 device is ethernet, not wireless. You have apparently attempted, unsuccessfully, to get ndiswrapper to work for your ethernet device. I suggest that you remove it:

```
sudo apt purge ndiswrapper
sudo rm -r /etc/ndiswrapper/*
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
```

Next, you evidently attempted to install a Broadcom driver, *wl*, for your Realtek device; let's remove it also:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Next, let's try a driver parameter to see if we can improve the connectivity:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Then set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After these changes, reboot and test.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I have deleted the mentioned wrong software and set my REGDOMAIN=DE but unfortunately i am still facing the problem.